# Will git push --force delete remote files?

Tags: git, push, git-remote

If i perform a `git push --force <remoterepo> <remotebranch>`

will this delete files in the `<remotebranch>`, if these do not exist in my branch?

(apart of course from prioritizing my local changes over remote ones, when it comes to files existing in both local and remote branches)

Comment: Yes, it will delete those files. Note that this is not a "secure" way of deleting files though, so don't use this method to delete files you "accidentally" pushed, like config files with live passwords or such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HEAD commit of that remote branch will reflect the commit you are pushing.
If that commit does not include certain files, there won't be in the remote branch HEAD as well.

But their history will be preserved in past commits, unless the `push --force` rewrite *all* the commits in which those files were present. That happens typically if your `push --force` is done after a [`git filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch).